# Operar una variable php

Tags: php

**Estoy tratando de operar una varible que dentro de ella tiene formulas matematicas**

Se puede operar lo que tenga dentro de una variable ??, sin que me retorne el texto como string?

*Ejemplo:*

```
$p = "1 + 2";
echo $p; // 1 + 2
```

Cuando quisiera que me retornara el valor de la operación que está como string

```
$p = "1+2";
echo $p; // 3;
```

existe alguna forma de hacer esto con php???

Comment: No se si te refieres a esto: `$p = (1+2);` o esto: `$p = 1 + 2;`... si lo encierras entre comillas siempre lo interpretará como string.

Comment: Osea, quisiera que de alguna forma el sacara ese string y lo utilizara como que fueran numero y símbolos matemáticos.

Comment: Entonces quizás querrás esto:  `eval("echo $p;");` aunque no lo recomiendo. La función eval() siempre hay que evitarla por el peligro que comporta en cuanto a seguridad. *If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP*

Comment: Muchas gracias @masterguru, es exactamente lo que buscaba que ejecute código de forma arbitraria sin embargo el código lo ejecutara mi controlador nadie más que yo tendré acceso a ese fragmento.

Comment: José Vásquez... tú lo programas y tú decides, pero aunque sólo tu controlador lo ejecutará... ¿de dónde salen las fórmulas? ¿En algún momento el usuario puede introducir/modificar esas fórmulas? Si es así, ¡huye! O al menos haz una evaluación de si el contenido es una expresión matemática válida con expresiones regulares o similares.
Ejemplos de peligros hay bastantes. Alguno puedes verlo en https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179375/how-eval-in-php-can-be-dangerous-in-web-applications-security o en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php